# Can I use the soldier's old v_model hand instead of the c_model in TF2?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, tf2-soldier

For the past couple of years I have been playing TF2. After the LaW update there was a change in the player models and animations. In this question, I am referring specifically to the **soldier** model.

My question is if there is a way to use the old v_model instead of the newer c_model, since the model's hands are dramatically different. These two pictures compare them:

Old (v_model) soldier hand:
[image: Old Soldier hand]

New (c_model) Soldier hand:
[image: New Soldier hand]

This has been bugging me for a while as I feel the newer model's hand is terrible.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. As far as I could find very few weapons will allow the use of v models. The ones that will allow v model are Stickybomb Launcher, Minigun, Revolver, Knife, and Red Tape Recorder. No other models will accept a v model.

Comment: Is there some sort of TF2 skin that allows the Soldier's hand to have this model? Instead of using the v model for it.

Comment: You could edit the 3D model file itself to your liking however this would be extremely difficult. The rocket laucher 3D model file should contain the soldier's hand so it would just be a matter of changing the hand shape. Once you have remodeled it you could retexture it. Again, this would be extremely difficult. There is a small possibility that you could find the old vmodel for the soldier's rocket laucher and rename it cmodel but I'm not sure that will work.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! Is there a way to find that with a certain way?

Comment: As far as I know there is really no way to backtrack versions of TF2 so your only hope is to find a mod that for some reason contains the vmodel. However, if a mod does contain the vmodel is has most likey been edited from it's original state. Maybe you could hop on [Game Banana](http://gamebanana.com/games/297) and ask if anyone has the old tf2_misc_dir file that contains the old vmodels. Then you would just extract the rocket launcher files using [GCF Scape](http://nemesis.thewavelength.net/?p=26) . I don't think anyone will have the old files but it's worth a try.